# How do I create rows from an array to create a view in phpMy Admin - mySql

Tags: mysql, select, view

this is my current table

| meta_ID | post_id | Meta_key | Meta_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5510 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-07-18,2022-07-25 |
| 2 | 6099 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-07-18,2022-07-25 |
| 3 | 6208 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-05-09,2022-08-18 |

What query do I need to use to select the following rows to allow me to create a database view like this?

| post_id | Meta_key | Meta_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5510 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-07-18 |
| 5510 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-07-25 |
| 6099 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2021-12-27 |
| 6099 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-01-27 |
| 6208 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-05-09 |
| 6208 | tourmaster-tour-date | 2022-08-18 |

Answer (score 0):

Yes - running that does create a table with those details in....how do I do this on the fly?

these dates will be added to on a hourly basis.

I need run an SQL that will list all of the individual dates from the meta_value column as individual rows. I then want to join that with other tables to create a report of all the dates and who has booked what - does that make sense?

[here is the screen shot of the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfaSh.png)